# Toad For MySql Give error on new connection

Tags: mysql, toad

Recently i installed Toad For MySQL latest version but when ever i create new connection i got this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following condition

- `root` user has privilege to connect to `localhost`
- you have given right password for the user `root`